# UITextView removes all third party keyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uikeyboard

EDIT: I figured out the problem.
Under the Attributes inspector, I had "secure text entry" enabled, which caused the problems

When I tap my UITextView, I only get the alphanumeric keyboard, despite having a third party keyboard. I also noticed in iOS simulator that the UITextView does not allow emojis, despite not saying to do so. My UITextField (on the same screen) causes no problems.

What could be causing this error?

This is What I am Getting

[image: This is What I Don't Want]

This is what I don't want

[image]

Comment: why did i get -1ed? I'm asking a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Your Keyboard settings,In attributes inspector keyboard type default to anything else which one needed. It will help you

[image]

You will get this

[image]

Comment: it will surely work.What type of keyboard you using?

Comment: accepted your answer because my problem was unusual, I had secure text entry selected

Answer (score 1):

from story board with your `textview` selected change `keyboard type` to `default` from `attribute inspector`. I think you have change keyboard type accidently.

And if that is not work that means your third party library is changing keyboard type somewhere then you can set `keyboard type` `programmatically` in your `viewdidload` method like

```
 self.yourTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: have you try to set programmaticly ? and which third party are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you enable the secure text entry the system will limit the third party keyboard. Maybe you can custom your own keyboard.